# iteration on keypress

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to make a program in Python that will capture and save a unique screenshot each time I press 'Enter'. I am having problems with assigning unique file names to said screenshots. Here is my code piece concerning capturing a screenshot:

```
def on_press(key):
if key == Key.enter:
    x = 1
    bitmap = autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
    bitmap.save('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\Capture{}.png'.format(x))
    x += 1
```

As you can see I initialized a variable x that I want to increase in value by 1 each time I press 'Enter'. The sequence of program would be this: press Enter -> capture screenshot 1 -> increase x value by one -> press Enter -> capture screenshot 2 -> increase x value by one (and so forth). I tried to use for loops to change the value of x but the result usually involves capturing multitude of screenshots all at once after I have pressed 'Enter'. How to solve it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def on_press(key):
    if key == Key.enter:
        x = 1
        bitmap = autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
        bitmap.save('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\Capture{}.png'.format(x))
        x += 1
```

The code is not correctly indented in your question. Then, 'x' inside a function is a 'local' variable. It will not have the correct value on the next call. You could define a global instance of x like this:

```
x = 1

def on_press(key):
    global x
    if key == Key.enter:
        bitmap = autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
        bitmap.save('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\Capture{}.png'.format(x))
        x += 1
```

Comment: Your code throws an "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment" Exception. A `global` statement is missing.

Comment: Sorry - sunday morning. Add global x to the function (edited the original answer)

Answer (score 0):

Every time, `key` is set to `Key.enter`, you reset the value of `x` back to `1`. Therefore `x` will always `1`, when you save the file. You need to save the state of `x` outside the function.

```
x = 1

def on_press(key):
    global x
    if key == Key.enter:
        bitmap = autopy.bitmap.capture_screen()
        bitmap.save('C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder\Capture{}.png'.format(x))
        x += 1
```